# Who does the peer review of edits?

Tags: support, edits, review, suggested-edits

I didn't find this anywhere: who is doing the peer review of edits?

Comment: Peers. I, for example, am the Earl of Carlton.

Comment: Hmm - OK, so there was an answer and I'm getting downvoted.   It seems I can't delete this question now that it has an answer as well.   Damn!   Is that right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Those who have the required amount of reputation on that particular site can review the edits in the suggested edits review queue.  On most sites that is 2000 rep.  For Tag wikis it usually requires 5000 rep.  It takes 2 reviewers to approve the edit.  See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work) for more details.